# How to reshape a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reshape

I would like to reshape a `DataFrame`, but I am not sure what the best way is to do this:

The original dataframe is:

> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b','b'],'B':[1,2,2,3]})

And I would like to reshape it to:

> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[2,3]})

Could somebody explain me how to do this best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot` after reorganizing a bit the input:

```
(df1.assign(index=df1.groupby('A').cumcount())
    .pivot(index='index', columns='A', values='B')
    .rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

or `unstack`:

```
(df1.set_index([df1.groupby('A').cumcount(), 'A'])
    .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
    a  b   
0   1  2
1   2  3
```